# Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: oop

```
    function im_check_term($name,$tax){
        $term =  get_term_by("name", $name,$tax);
        return !is_wp_error($term) ? $term->term_id : false;
    }
```

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/pcodecom/demo.p30code.com/multimedia-2/wp-content/plugins/imdb/imdb.php on line 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) for `get_term_by()`, you'll see that it:

> Will return false if `$taxonomy` does not exist or `$term` was not found.

You need to account for this possibility in your code by checking the value of `$term`. You'll also note from the documentation that `get_term_by()` does *not* return a `WP_Error`, so `is_wp_error()` is not useful. This is what you need:

```
$term = get_term_by( 'name', $name, $tax );

return $term ? $term->term_id : false;
```

The specific error you're seeing is because if `$term` is `false` then `$term->term_id` is invalid code.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) might return the boolean value `false`. So the simple check for a `WP_Error` is not sufficient. Use the `instanceof` operator instead and test for a `WP_Term` object:

```
function im_check_term($name,$tax){
    $term =  get_term_by("name", $name,$tax);
    return ( $term instanceof WP_Term ) ? $term->term_id : false;
}
```